# ¿Como seleccionar datos que no esten guardadas en un registro?

Tags: php, mysql

Saludos, explico lo que trato de hacer: tengo estudiantes inscritos en cursos. Pero el sistema debe tener la capacidad de que un solo estudiante pueda estar en 1 o mas cursos, el problema no es ese porque cuando inscribo otros cursos al mismo estudiante lo hace bien, aqui viene mi necesidad, cuando voy a inscribir otro curso a un estudiante muestro los cursos disponibles mediante un select, pero resulta que en el select me muestra el o los cursos en los que el estudiante ya esta inscrito, deberia de mostrar solo los cursos en los que no esta inscrito, se que eso tiene que ver algo con el DISTINCTROW, pero en realidad no se como plantear mi sentencia SQL, en lo que refiere a las tablas de la base de datos dejare la imagen de donde me traigo los cursos disponibles, la tabla estudiantes, y la tabla donde guardo las inscripciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución no es un JOIN, lo que debes hacer es una consulta a la tabla de **CURSOS_ABIERTOS** junto con a una condición a la que se le aplica un subselect de los cursos diferentes al que el estudiante esta registrado en la tabla **INSCRITOS**:

```
SELECT* FROM CURSOS_ABIERTOS AS C
WHERE C.id NOT IN (
    SELECT I.id_curso FROM INSCRITOS AS I
    WHERE I.id_student = 'TuEstudiante'
)
```

El subselect devuelve los cursos donde está ya inscrito. Saludos  disculpa por la respuesta anterior.

Comment: Saludos Rostan, gracias por la respuesta, apoyandome en lo que me planteas solo no entiendo en el WHERE I.id_student = ' ' esas comillas en blanco porque?

Comment: Dentro de las comillas simples debe ir el id_student que estas buscando.

Comment: $query = "SELECT cursos_abiertos.id,cursos_abiertos.curso FROM 
   inscritos INNER JOIN cursos_abiertos
  ON inscritos.id_curso=cursos_abiertos.id WHERE inscritos.id_student =  '$id' AND cursos_abiertos.curso IS NOT NULL";                               asi he hecho la sentencia Rostan pero me esta mostrando solo el curso que tiene inscrito el estudiante.

Comment: Pruebalo así, cometí un error especificando la tabla de pivote.

Comment: Sigue igual, pero ese FULL OUTER no me lo corre aqui. Estoy usando Mysql en phpmyadmin. No se si sea por eso.

Comment: La cuestion seria mostrar los cursos que tengan id distinto a los que tiene ele studiante registrado como cursos inscritos.

Comment: Mis disculpas por la respuesta anterior, me deje llevar por los joins. Esa es la respuesta correcta, saludos!.

Comment: Solucionado Rostan. Muchisimas Gracias.

Comment: Fue un gusto, suerte y exitos!